# Gradient border has slice but still only shows corners

Tags: css, linear-gradients, border-image

I added border-image-slice but the border still shows only the corners. It's also displaying outside of the striped border when I want it to lay directly over top of it. What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
          background-color: BLACK;
      background: url('https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_KSExlbMQsT842613856.jpg') repeat;
          }
    #header {
           padding: 10px;
              align-items: center;
        background: WHITE;
        display: inline-flex;
              align-items: center;
              justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
         }
         .border {
              position: relative;
              z-index: -1;
              border: 10px solid #6b36ba;
              border-image: url('https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_pa75I1OyXe388988805.jpg') 30 round;
        }
            .bordershine {
           display: flex;
              margin: 20px;
        border-width: 10px;
        border-style: solid;

              box-shadow:
                   0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset,
                   0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                   0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;

        border-image-slice: 10;
              border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
         }
```

```html
          <div class="bordershine">
              <div id="header" class="border">
                   <img src='https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_9cGq7M7RLK201862878.gif' alt='[Spinning Logo]'>
                   Hard Candy by IshikaruTanaka
              </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slice need to be after the `border-image`

```css
body {
  background-color: BLACK;
  background: url('https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_KSExlbMQsT842613856.jpg') repeat;
}

#header {
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  background: WHITE;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.border {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 10px solid #6b36ba;
  border-image: url('https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_pa75I1OyXe388988805.jpg') 30 round;
}

.bordershine {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset, 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 50%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 51%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  border-image-slice: 10;
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}
```

```html
<div class="bordershine">
  <div id="header" class="border">
    <img src='https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_9cGq7M7RLK201862878.gif' alt='[Spinning Logo]'> Hard Candy by IshikaruTanaka
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use `border-image-source`

```css
body {
  background-color: BLACK;
  background: url('https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_KSExlbMQsT842613856.jpg') repeat;
}

#header {
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  background: WHITE;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.border {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 10px solid #6b36ba;
  border-image: url('https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_pa75I1OyXe388988805.jpg') 30 round;
}

.bordershine {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset, 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
  border-image-slice: 10;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 50%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 51%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}
```

```html
<div class="bordershine">
  <div id="header" class="border">
    <img src='https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_9cGq7M7RLK201862878.gif' alt='[Spinning Logo]'> Hard Candy by IshikaruTanaka
  </div>
</div>
```

`border-image` is a shorthand property that include the `border-slice` so if you set it later it will override the previous `border-slice`

You can also use only `border-image` like you did with `.border`

```css
body {
  background-color: BLACK;
  background: url('https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_KSExlbMQsT842613856.jpg') repeat;
}

#header {
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  background: WHITE;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.border {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 10px solid #6b36ba;
  border-image: url('https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_pa75I1OyXe388988805.jpg') 30 round;
}

.bordershine {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset, 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 50%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 51%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 100%) 10;
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
}
```

```html
<div class="bordershine">
  <div id="header" class="border">
    <img src='https://userimages-akm.imvu.com/userdata/05/31/59/66/userpics/Snap_9cGq7M7RLK201862878.gif' alt='[Spinning Logo]'> Hard Candy by IshikaruTanaka
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect!